# Existe algum problema com ponteiros nesta struct que trabalha com listas encadeada?

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, lista-encadeada

Olá. Estou desenvolvendo um jogo com a linguagem C++ e acho que estou cometendo algum erro na utilização de listas encadeadas.

Ressalto que sei que existem recursos mais interessantes do que usar listas encadeadas em C++, mas esse é um projeto que fiz para faculdade, antes da matéria de Orientação a Objetos, logo é melhor que seja feito desta forma, neste projeto.

No geral, o jogo funciona bem. Porém ,de forma imprevísvel, ele dá e fica em uma tela preta com uma frequência razoável. Isso acontece apenas nos momentos que eu utilizo listas encadeadas. Sabendo que eu utilizei listas encadeadas de forma bastante semelhante no projeto, podemos supor que o erro está na forma que estou utilizando.

Eis, então, o exemplo mais simples de uso de listas encadeadas no meu projeto - uma struct que vem a ser um radiobutton:

---

```
// Botão do tipo radio (semelhante ao usado na Web)

struct Radio{

    static const int RAIO = 10;
    int x,y;
    bool checked;
    Radio *prox;
    char *label;

    // Funções
    Radio *Insere(Radio *radio0, char* label1, bool checked1, int meuX, int meuY);
    void LimpaNo(Radio *radio0);
    void CheckRadio(Radio *radio0);
    void VerificaClick(Radio *radio0);
    void MostraLista(Radio *radio0);
    Radio *RadioChecked(Radio *radio0);

    // "Construtor"
    void Init(char *label, bool checked, int meuX, int meuY);
};


// Limpa o nó da lista encadeada
void Radio::LimpaNo(Radio *radio0){
    Radio *pRadio, *aux;
    pRadio = radio0;
    while(pRadio != NULL){
        aux = pRadio;
        pRadio = pRadio->prox;
        free(aux);
    }
    radio0 = NULL;
}


// Retorna o Radio que foi selecionado
Radio* Radio::RadioChecked(Radio *radio0){

    Radio *pRadio;
    pRadio = radio0->prox;
    while(1){

        if (pRadio->checked == true || pRadio == NULL)
            return pRadio;

        pRadio = pRadio->prox;  
    }
}



// Liga o radio selecionado e desliga todos outros
void Radio::CheckRadio(Radio *radio0){

    Radio *pRadio;
    for(pRadio = radio0->prox; pRadio != NULL; pRadio = pRadio->prox ){
        pRadio->checked = false;    
    }
    this->checked = true;
}


// Mostra a lista de botões Radio
void Radio::MostraLista(Radio *radio0){
    Radio *pRadio;

    setcolor(LIGHTGREEN);
    setfillstyle(1,LIGHTGREEN);

    for(pRadio = radio0->prox; pRadio != NULL; pRadio = pRadio->prox){

        outtextxy(pRadio->x + 15, pRadio->y + 5, pRadio->label);
        if(pRadio->checked == false)
            circle(pRadio->x,pRadio->y,RAIO);
        else
            fillellipse(pRadio->x,pRadio->y,RAIO,RAIO);
    }
}


// Verifica possíveis clicks em todo botões Radio
void Radio::VerificaClick(Radio *radio0){

    Radio *pRadio;
    int mouseX,mouseY;
    double tempX, tempY, distRaio;
    bool checkRadio = false;

    if(GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x80){

        mouseX = mousex();
        mouseY = mousey();
        for(pRadio = radio0->prox; pRadio != NULL; pRadio = pRadio->prox){

            tempX = pow(pRadio->x - mouseX,2.0);
            tempY = pow(pRadio->y - mouseY,2.0);
            distRaio = sqrt(tempX + tempY);

            if(distRaio <= RAIO){
                pRadio->CheckRadio(radio0);     
            }
        }
    }
}


// Insere um novo botão de rádio na lista encadeada radio0
Radio* Radio::Insere(Radio *radio0, char* label1, bool checked1, int meuX, int meuY){

    Radio *novo;
    novo = (Radio *) malloc(sizeof(Radio));
    novo->Init(label1,checked1,meuX,meuY); 
    novo->prox  = radio0->prox;
    radio0->prox = novo;
    return novo;    
}

//============================================================
// Atribui os dados de um novo botão
void Radio::Init(char *label1, bool checked1, int meuX, int meuY){
    x = meuX;
    y = meuY;
    checked = checked1;
    label = label1;
    prox = NULL;
}
```

---

Comment: Eu acho que a pergunta está muito ampla então nem vou tentar responder. Até porque o que mais posso ajudar de verdade não responderia diretamente o que foi perguntado, apesar de ajudar na solução. O que posso te adiantar é que se está usando C++, tem várias técnicas melhores para fazer a lista encadeada (entendo o uso dela, e pode ser adequada sim). A alocação de memória em C++ é feita de outra forma e dá para deixar o gerenciamento de ponteiros de forma automática, o que facilita muito o seu uso e talvez até resolva o problema que está ocorrendo. Misturar C com C++ é aprender errado.

Comment: o código tem problema de arquitetura também. É claro que não vai causar grandes problemas. Mas se é para aprender é melhor aprender certo. Está misturando conceitos, a lista deveria ser uma coisa, a sua apresentação deveria ser outra coisa. Eu sei que no início do aprendizado é comum não pensar muito nisto. Mas não vejo valor em aprender fazer coisas mais complicadas no início da aprendizagem. Note que estou falando de complicação e não complexidade.

Comment: @bigown, concordo que existe uma mistura de elementos de C e C++ aí. E é claro, deve-se sempre procurar as melhores práticas. Se está deste jeito, é porque ainda não tenho conhecimentos sólidos em nenhuma das duas linguagens. Mesmo assim, o jogo funciona de forma geral e até funciona em rede. Pessoas divertiram-se quando o bug não ocorria.

Comment: Então, não julgo que eu deva voltar a estaca de um duradouro aprendizado na linguagem para poder terminar o projeto. Existe mais de uma maneira de resolver os problemas.

Minha pergunta refere-se apenas a erros de ponteiros. Quero saber se há alguma parte do código que pode fazer algo errado como utilizar um ponteiro que não foi inicializado, por exemplo.

Comment: @KelvinOliveira Que tal executar o jogo em modo de depuração para conseguir a informação de qual linha está causando o travamento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Bom, talvez até exista um erro de ponteiro nesta `struct`. Mas, com relação ao erro da tela preta, esse foi resolvido.

O erro era causado pela elevada frequência de uso de uma função que trocava a fonte do texto do jogo - a função `settextstyle()`. Isso poderia ser diagnosticado com base no fato que a fonte, durante o bug da tela preta, não era coerente com o que foi programado.

Então, se alguém for utilizar a antiga biblioteca gráfica WinBGI  para fazer algo - biblioteca essa que, na verdade, só serve para dar um pontapé inicial na programação de jogos - , posso dizer que tive que evitar o uso desta função para que esse bug não ocorresse.

Agradeço a todos que responderam a pergunta (Pablo e Maniero no momento desta resposta, obrigado pessoal). Se alguém tiver interesse pelo jogo - que é um Tower Defense na 2ª Guerra e com 4 finais - é só entrar em contato que eu passo mais informações.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]